# Restrict text in text radtextbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, telerik

i want to restrict text box text to give only there of the following(1.0,1.5,2.0) remaining values are not acceptable, here for min and max values i can use range validator but how can i restrict only up to these values.
Text box should takes only 1.0 or 1.5 or 2.0 only, help me in doing this.

thanks in advance.

Comment: ya we can do like that, i want only textbox based on my requirement. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do with RadTextBox alone.

The following code uses onKeyPress event to check whether input character is valid or not.

Then let RegularExpressionValidator to validate the final value.

```
<telerik:RadTextBox runat="server" ID="RadTextBox1" MaxLength="3">
    <ClientEvents OnKeyPress="onKeyPress" />
</telerik:RadTextBox>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator runat="server"
    ControlToValidate="RadTextBox1"
    ID="RegularExpressionValidator1"
    ValidationExpression="^(1.0|1.5|2.0)$"
    ErrorMessage="Must be 1.0, 1.5 or 2.0.">
</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function onKeyPress(sender, eventArgs) {
        var char = eventArgs.get_keyCharacter();
        if (char == "0" || char == "1" || char == "2" || 
            char == "5" || char == ".") {
            // Acceptable input
        } else {
            eventArgs.set_cancel(true);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Here j just used the regular expression validator in the above code, no need to use script as regular expression fires for other values,thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a combo box and add the values you need to it. The user will be forced to chose one of the available values.
[image]

Comment: can't we do with the textbox?

Comment: Use TextChanged event to do this validation.

Comment: You can do it in many ways. The problem I see here is that the user does not know what to input in the text box unless you propose him something. The easiest way is a comboBox where the user will have simply to chose which value to use. Look at my answer above. Why you cannot use a comboBox?

Comment: @FeliceM, i can use drop down here, but i can't argue with my higher authority, i should do what they want, that is way i am trying.

Comment: Then just use textChanged event as suggested by Bappi with some if statement to validate the entry. Good luck.